# Is there a script to bypass 50000 characters for in-cell formula?

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have this (insanely) long formula I need to run in Google Sheets, and I came across the limit error:

> #### There was a problem
>
> Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell.

[image]

**Is there a workaround for this?**

---

my formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY({B!A1:A100; ........ ; CA!DZ1:DZ100}, 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))
```

full formula is:  **pastebin.com/raw/ZCkZahpw**

apologies for Pastebin... I got a few errors here too:

[image]

[image]

**note 1:** due to fact that it's a long formula, the output from it should be of size ~100 rows × 3 columns
**note 2:** so far I managed to bypass `JOIN`/`TEXTJOIN` for 50000+ characters even 500000 limits for total cells

Comment: If your formula is in excess of 50000 characters then you might need to go back to the drawing board and rethink your approach. Can you give us step-by-step break down of what you are trying to achieve? We can't provide any guidance without knowing what your goals are.

Comment: @DimuDesigns answer updated. step-by-step break down: every range contains either empty cells (eg. nothing) or mix of empty cells and cells with 3 words. goal is to construct array with `{}` and filter out empty cells from that array with query. then split those 3-word cells into 3 columns of words

Comment: If the rest of the cells are empty in each range, create a open range: `A!A:A` instead of `A!A1:A100`.  That's almost a 50% reduction in size.

Comment: Also remove `select *`, `asc`, etc. `"where Col1!=''order by Col1"` should be enough. I still don't think you'll reach <50k limit. But, still worth a shot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to recommend  a work around to a Google limit which seems more than reasonable.

Comment: @Cooper "because it's asking us to recommend a workaround to a Google limit which seems more than reasonable." dude... don't twist my words to fit your justification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE:

I managed to enter up to **323461** characters as a formula! by using <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd> where I replaced simple **`=SUM(1)`** formula with my huge formula from this answer: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131019/186471**

### ___________________________________________________________

after some research, it looks like there isn't any workaround to pull this of.

recommended savings that were suggested ( shortening: `A!A:A`, dropping: `select *`, `asc`,  shortening: `"where Col1!=''order by Col1"`) reduced it a bit and rest was split into two formulas in VR `{}` array solution.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a script to bypass 50000 characters for in-cell formula?

If the length of `{B!A1:A100; ........ ; CA!DZ1:DZ100}` is greater than 50 thousands characters consider to build a custom function that build the array for you. You could "hard-code" the references or list them as text on a range to be read by your script.

Then, the resulting formula could look like this:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(MYCUSTOMFUNCTION(), 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))
```

or like this

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(MYCUSTOMFUNCTION(A1:A1000), 
 "select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc", 0), " "))
```

(assuming that you have 1000 references).

A custom function works because it on the Google Sheets side instead of having a formula that exceeds the cell content limit it will use just few characters and because by using good practices it's possible to make that it takes less than the 30 seconds time execution limit for them.

It's worth to note that if the `MYCUSTOMFUNCTION()` variant  (without arguments) is used, it only will be recalculated when the spreadsheet is opened but the `MYCUSTOMFUNCTION(A1:A1000)` variant (with a range reference as argument) will be recalculated every time that a cell in the range reference changes.

References

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheets/sheet#getdatarange)