# How to shorten a formula with a OR comparing several RIGHT functions in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to solve this problem:

I need to shorten the following formula:

```
=IFS(
OR(
RIGHT(A1,1)="^",
RIGHT(A1,1)="*",
RIGHT(A1,2)="@@",
RIGHT(A1,2)="%%"),
1,TRUE,0)
```

I thought of using the pipe symbol like this:

```
=IFS(
OR(
RIGHT(A1,1)="^|*",
RIGHT(A1,2)="@@|%%"),
1,TRUE,0)
```

But it's not working.

How to shorten this formula?

Comment: I can't think of a way to shorten what you have in your question, but I notice you are using `IFS` and not `IF`. Perhaps if you provide the entire formula and describe what you want to achieve we could find a way to help?

Comment: Hi cybernetic.nomad. Thanks for your comment. @player0 gave a great and helpful solution. I had reached the 50k characters limit and needed to shorten my Right function. Take care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` can be used only in regex formulas. what about this:

```
=N(REGEXMATCH(A1, "\^$|\*$|@@$|%%$"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi @player0! Thanks a lot for the working answer! As always you rock! Thanks also for the explanation about the pipe working only with regexes. I had reached the 50k characters limit because of many embedded RIGHT formulas. Just a question: I made it work without the `N` at the beginning like this: `REGEXMATCH(A1, "\^$|\*$|@@$|%%$")` . What is the `N` good for? Many thanks again!

Comment: `N` converts `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0`

Comment: also to bypass 50k fx limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070275/5632629

Comment: Ok, thanks that simplify things to work with the nums. Thanks for letting me know. I'll check the new shared post too. Be well! talk soon, have a great (end of) ID (If you're in the US)!