# Is there any formula length limitation in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm trying to create a data array from multiple cells in one cell and fail:

My data is placed in cells from A3 to A3000. I try to paste into A1 the formula like `=A3&"|"&A4&"|"&A...&"|"&A3000`. The length of this formula is 29.345 characters - fewer than the limit of 50.000 characters à cell.

But just after pasting of formula into A1 I get an error from Google Sheets "Can't load the file. Try later or send bug report".

The only thing I suppose is, that there are some different limits for the length of formulas, then they are for the strings... Or does somebody know, what happens here and how could I overcome this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any formula length limitation

yes there is but it can be surpassed - **https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070275/5632629**
so far my longest formula had **422 379** characters

are you sure you need to do it like that (unclear from your question) instead of just:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A3:A3000)
```

or maybe even like (it really depends on what you want to do next):

```
=QUERY(A3:A3000,,999^99)
```

or perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A3000&"|")
```

Comment: the first formula helped. The result of textjoins should serve as part of RegEx extension. And it was too long for RegEx. In my case, i was forced to split the data column into two textjoins and then add two RegExs with an OR. But finally got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727816/is-there-a-script-to-bypass-50000-characters-for-in-cell-formula), I think the limit for formulas is the same as for content.

I would suggest trying to solve this with a custom formula in Apps Script.

```
function concatValues(range) {
  return range.join("|")
}
```

Then run your custom formula with `=concatValues(A3:A3000)`.