# Google Sheets How To convert whole column to a string

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a question. I have a column in Google Sheet something like [here][1]

```
------------------
| hello           |
-------------------
| my name is John |
-------------------
| Nice to meet you|
-------------------
```

Question is: How can I get a string like "***hello, my name is John, nice to meet you***" from it?

Comment: What have you tried o far?

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
=JOIN(", ", A1:A3)
```

or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, A:A)
```

if you want it without comma use:

```
=TRIM(QUERY(A:A,, 99^99))
```

---

`JOIN` and `TEXTJOIN` are limited to join up to 50 000 characters only. if your dataset is larger do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(A:A, "where A is not null", 0)&",",,99^99))
```

Comment: 9^9 is already exceeding the maximum number of cells allowed in a single workbook right? That is a very interesting glitch using headers in query to exceed the maximum allowed by even `&` is there a real character limit per cell I thought it was 50k. Pretty cool.

Comment: yes for 9^9 and yes there is a limit but also a workaround how to bypass that limit. for string its this QUERY smash and for formula - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070275/5632629

Comment: Please provide the link to the bypassing of 5 million cell limit! I can't wait to make almost completely unusable spreadsheets haha!

Answer (score 1):

Google sheets has a special function just for this, true here means ignore all the blank cells, and we are assuming you always want a comma and a space after each cell.

```
=textjoin(", ",true,A:A)
```

Comment: @Datanovice I was assuming the example he gave was just column A:A how do you understand it?

Comment: Great answer just tested on a sample sheet. I thought he wanted every word split by a comma!