# Remove stop words with matching case

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution

I'm currently using this formula to remove the stop words from a list of words:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"or|and|but|for|of",""),",,",",")
```

However, it also removed some letters in some words which are not stop words. Ex: n**or**d, **for**eign. Is there any way to remove the words with the matching case only?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\b(or|and|but|for|of)\b", ), ",,", ",")
```

[image]

---

upgrade:

```
=JOIN(",", SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\b(or|and|but|for|of)\b", ), ", "))
```

[image]

Comment: Just `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s*\b(or|and|but|for|of)\b,?\s*","")` would do.

Comment: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\s+\b(or|and|but|for|of)\b,?\s+", )` doesn't work but 
`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\s*\b(or|and|but|for|of)\b,?\s*","")` works correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I compiled this huge regex and list of stop words with adverbs and adjectives and the months here https://web.archive.org/web/20230216023942/https://rentry.co/2fve82 and here https://web.archive.org/web/20230216021429/https://rentry.co/3ibya and reached the 50k characters cell limit but could perform this workaround by player0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070275/10789707